# Grocery crud callback issue

Tags: php, grocery-crud

I want to add the text "Login Details:" Before the field Email in the edit section of grocery crud. What callback is required to achieve this?

It Looks like this when we click on the action "edit" of grocery crud:

`Email: (Textbox)
Username: (Textbox)`

It should look like this:
Login Details:

`Email: (Textbox)
Username: (Textbox)`

Answer (score 0):

```
void display_as($field_name, $display_as)
```

Changes the displaying label of the field

Answer (score 0):

```
$crud->display_as($fieldname, $display_as);
```

It will change label of the field.